# Variance of Order Statistics

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, statistics, order-statistics

I have a question about bounding the variance of order statistics.

Given that for $i \in \{1,\cdots,\lambda\}$, denote $Bin(s,\frac{1}{n})$ to be a binomial random variable with success probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and $s$ independent experiments. Define $W_i=Bin(n-s,\frac{1}{n})-Bin(s,\frac{1}{n})$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is some constant w.r.t s and $\lambda$. All $W_i$ are i.i.d random variables.

Is there any estimate that I can use to upper bound the variance of the largest order statistics $Z= \max_{i \in [\lambda]}\{W_i\}$, i.e. $Var(Z)\leq U$?

I am aware that we can use $\max_{i \in [\lambda]}\{W_i\}\leq \sum W_i$ to bound the variance $Var(Z)\leq \sum Var(W_i)=\lambda * n \frac{1}{n}(1-\frac{1}{n})= \lambda(1-\frac{1}{n})$.

But I wonder whether we can derive any tighter upper bound in this case. So we can bound the variance within some lower order term in $\lambda$ or even constant $O(1)$.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give an explicit bound, but I would have thought that, since the $W_i$s themselves are independent with their distribution able to take values on the integers in $[-s,n-s]$, the variance of their maximum would eventually be decreasing toward $0$ as $\lambda \to \infty$, since the distribution of the maximum would eventually concentrate near $n-s$.

I would have guessed that the variance of the maximum was bounded by the case of $\lambda=1$ which, as you say, is $1-\frac1n$, which in turn is bounded above by $1$.

Here is a simulation using R, with $n=10$, $s=7$, and $\lambda$ taking values from $1$ to $150$.  Unexpectedly, even allowing for simulation noise, it suggests that the variance of the maximum is not a decreasing function of $\lambda$ everywhere.

```
maxW <- function(n, s, lambda){
  W <- rbinom(lambda, n-s, 1/n) - rbinom(lambda, s, 1/n)
  return(max(W))
  }

n <- 10
s <- 7
maxlambda <- 150
cases <- 10^4
simvar <- numeric(maxlambda)

set.seed(2023)
for (lambda in 1:maxlambda){
  sims <- replicate(cases, maxW(n, s, lambda))
  simvar[lambda] <- var(sims)
  }
plot(1:maxlambda, simvar, ylim=c(0,1), xlab="lambda")
abline(h=0, col="black") 
abline(h=1-1/n, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have a similar guess as yours. While the simulation suggests there is a more complicated structure monotonicity of variance. I still think if we take $\lambda $ sufficiently large, we can bound this variance by $1$ or even better bound like $O(\frac{1}{\log(\lambda)})$ since in the simulation the overall trend is decreasing and they are all bounded by $1$ in this case. But I still have no clue how to come up with such an explicit bound.

Comment: @Lin.  It may not be easy.  Just playing with some other values such as $n=100$ and $s=90$, there are at least three local maxima, one at $\lambda=1$ and the others perhaps near $\lambda \approx 20$ and $\lambda \approx 400$  (the  $\lambda=1$ case is still the global maximum variance).

Comment: @ Henry. I agree with you. It is not easy. Maybe it can be analysed from some simple cases first. I have seen some paper concerning concentration of order statistics: https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.7209. In this paper, they use the Efron-Stein inequality to bound the variance of maxima of standard Gaussian random variables and show that $V(X_{(1)})$ (where $X_{(1)}$ denotes the largest order statistics) is bounded by $O(\frac{1}{\log(\lambda)})$ in Proposition 4.7. While I guess a similar approach can be applied to this problem. But there is still quite a gap between these two cases.